# Fancybox box isn't working after I upload it to webhost but works on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, fancybox

http://www.outofthegardendesigns.com

any thoughts?

I think it has something to do with the pathing but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: When I run this $('.fancybox') from console, it returns empty array. Are you sure, you have some element with class fancybox ? Because you are doing  $('.fancybox').fancybox() and its throwing error.

Comment: Yes. I'm mostly using .iframe on this page as a class. everything works when it's on local host as I said so it doesn't have to do with how I set up the button classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding jQuery multiple times.

Two times from this url `js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.js` and then again with google cdn and again a fallback if google cdn is offline. I guess, this is causing conflict. Since, on your localhost you may be offline, google cdn jQuery is not loading and everything is working fine. But when you open it in server, google cdn jQuery tries to load and takes time and throws an error.

Comment: So should I remove the Google cdn?

Comment: Remove all other versions. Keep the google cdn and its fallback and put that code above all (before using any jQuery)

Comment: That fixed the problem! but now in chrome the .iframe for the store i'snt working?

Comment: Its working fine now.
One more suggestion. Either add jQuery in `<head></head>` section or just before closing body tag (`</body>`).

And mark as answer, if my answer helped you :)

Comment: Well it's working in the other browsers. But just goes white when I hit store in chrome.. any ideas? and thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your links to fancybox and jquery is not correct. You have :

```
<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You need to add "/" at the begining of the links like:

```
<script src="/js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After removing extra jquyer link, your code should be look like this:

```
<script src="/js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.b2').animate({
            opacity:.0

        });

        $('.b2').hover(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1});


        }, function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0});

        });


    });
</script>


<!--FANCY BOX-->
<script src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure , because I never add '/' and it always work for me :O

Comment: well.. by doing that it detaches the .js file.

Comment: By the way you have jQuery source couple time. Remove all and keep just one at very top of all your code.

Comment: You have another link of jquery source at line 193. add "/" to that one and remove the one you have close to fancybox link.

Comment: The / is not what fixed it. That disabled the javascript from being sourced.