# Fancybox works on local host, but not on live hosted site

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

It seems as if other people have had this problem, but the solutions that I found on this site don't seem to fix my situation. I'm building a website in HubSpot and trying to add Fancybox, so when people click on the executive photos, a Fancybox/pop-up will appear with the bio. Here's a link to the page on the live hosted server (where the Fancybox pop-ups don't work).

http://www.huntzingergroup.com/about-us-v6-fancybox

The site works fine in the HubSpot testing environment, but not when I post it live on the hosted server. I've tested my links to my .js and .css files, and they appear to work. I believe I'm only loading one version of jquery. I've also implemented solutions from these articles:

[Fancybox box isn't working after I upload it to webhost but works on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052848/fancybox-box-isnt-working-after-i-upload-it-to-webhost-but-works-on-localhost)

[jQuery isn't functioning on different webhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391926/jquery-isnt-functioning-on-different-webhost)

Does anyone have any other ideas of how I may fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: The code on the website is minified. Can you create a JSFiddle or CodePen?

Comment: Below is the link to the JSFiddle. I haven't set one up before, so let me know if you need me to add other elements.
https://jsfiddle.net/BikingManatee/0zekpzrh/1/

Comment: I think I figured out the problem after changing some code in JSFiddle (thanks Toby for recommending JSFiddle -- I'll use that to troubleshoot my problems in the future!). It appears the Fancybox .had a conflict with the the act-async-load.js that HubSpot automatically loads in the header of each page on the site. When I remove the act-async-load.js script in the head of this page, the Fancybox .js works for the bio pop-ups.